# Trying to get templatebound style to update background color

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm just starting up on learning WPF stuff rather than Winforms and some differences are confusing me. I've set up a style for handling some navigation buttons and in the border, I've defined background="{templatebinding background}"

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border 
                    Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="3" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    >
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property ="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but my problem here is that the color of this background is not changing when I change the background color in C#.

```
if (btnNavHome.Background == Brushes.DarkSlateGray) 
{
    btnNavHome.Background = Brushes.CadetBlue;
}
```

I am unable to set the color of the background via behind-code. I assume it's working by passing the background value of the button to the border background when it is created; Am I missing something that would allow this to be passed dynamically?

I've only started learning xaml and wpf stuff two days ago and with no formal training, so I apologize if some of it is done in an inefficient way or if there's more information/context needed.

Here's the code that the button itself points at. It's just checking if any other canvases are visible and hiding them if they are then (trying to) recolor the button corresponding to the active canvas.

```
private void navHome()
        {
            DoubleAnimation loadIn = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)));
            DoubleAnimation loadOut = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)));

            if (canvasHome.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
            {
                if (canvasHome.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasHome.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadIn);
                    canvasHome.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                if (canvasRep.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasRep.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadOut);
                    canvasRep.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                if (canvasRepInq.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasRepInq.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadOut);
                    canvasRepInq.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                if (canvasInv.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasInv.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadOut);
                    canvasInv.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                if (canvasInvInq.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasInvInq.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadOut);
                    canvasInvInq.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                if (canvasDevInq.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    canvasDevInq.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, loadOut);
                    canvasDevInq.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }

                if (btnNavHome.Background == Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavHome.Background = Brushes.CadetBlue;
                if (btnNavRep.Background != Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavRep.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;
                if (btnNavRepInq.Background != Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavRepInq.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;
                if (btnNavInv.Background != Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavInv.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;
                if (btnNavInvInq.Background != Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavInvInq.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;
                if (btnNavDevInq.Background != Brushes.DarkSlateGray) btnNavDevInq.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;

            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the button where you use the style and can you please write if your code is getting into the _if-case_. Otherwise try it without the if condition to see if its work, if don't done before.

Comment: Added. There isn't much to it; Just some visibility stuff and trying to recolor the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the appending. Is the method: _navHome()_ execute (set an brackpoint into it and run the code)? Have you set an event or when did the code should execute the method _navHome()_? What I men with code was the XAML-Code of the button and should be placed in an file with the ending *.xaml (was not clear enough maybe from my side, sorry).

Comment: So with a breakpoint in there, it did what I did not expect. It does go into the if statements as it should. If I'm moving to the Home screen from the Rep screen, it sees that the btnNavHome.Background is DarkSlateGray and tries to set it to CadetBlue and it also sees that the btnNavRep is not DarkSlateGray so it tries to set it to DarkSlateGray but in my UI, they're both DarkSlateGray all the time; The colors themselves never visually change.

Comment: Alllllright, I feel dumb. I had the MyButton style applied to these buttons at one point and don't anymore. I set them to the NavButton style and changed the MyButton style to have templatebinding correct in MyButton but not in NavButton. Well thanks for helping me out!